# Binary search accessing out of range index

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, search

This is the code:

```
char binarySearch(unsigned int target, int* primes, unsigned int size){
    int* ptrToArray = primes;
    unsigned int first = 0;
    unsigned int last = size;

    while (first <= last){
        unsigned int middle = first + (last - first) / 2;
        printf("first: %d, last: %d, middle: %d\n", first, last , middle);

        if (ptrToArray[middle] == target){
            return 1;
        }

        if (ptrToArray[middle] < target){
            first = middle + 1;
        }else{
            last = middle - 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

[image]

I've been staring at that peace of code for more than one should and still can't figure out where is the flaw.

Comment: @Thomas yes, that is correct.

Comment: If `size` is not a valid value, you have to handle that case.

Comment: Also, simple math simplify  `first + (last - first) / 2` so it's more clear that it's the middle.

Comment: That is if `size <= 0`, you should return some error to let the user know that the array is not correct.

Comment: try  unsigned int last = size-1; instead of  unsigned int last = size;

Comment: @RahulSawant:: I don't think that is valid here.

Comment: @Abhineet Array of size 0 is perfectly defined (though buggy in this code). Agree for negative values though (or simply use `size_t`)

Comment: @amit: I was referring to the OP's code. There are other bugs too, I just pointed out the most obvious one :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `middle` is `0`, as near the end of your debug output, the statement

```
last = middle - 1
```

causes an integer overflow; the conditions have to be reworked a bit.

Comment: Something like: `last = (middle > 0)? middle - 1 : 0;`, probably?

Comment: `last = middle;`, exactly that. You will always get a new `middle`

Comment: @Ziezi There are no negative numbers so using `unsigned int` is safe and will not cause what others say except, `middle - 1`, so this is the correct answer. Note that `middle = (first + last) / 2` is always possitive, you just wrote it in a way that has a `-` sign, and it might look dangerous to unexperienced.

Answer (score 2):

You may get an out of bound when you are looking for an element not in the array, and is bigger than the array, due to allowing keep iteration when `last` and `first` equal each other in `while (first <= last)`

Think of what happens when you send an empty array: `size == 0`:

`first = 0, last = 0`, and thus: `(first <= last) == true`.

Then, `middle = 0 + (0 - 0)/2 = 0`, and next you access `ptrToArray[0]`, which is out of bound.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you define your index variables (`first`, `last`, `middle`) as `unsigned int` while in your logic, `last` can in fact become negative. However, in that case, since they're defined as `unsigned` and because of the way 2's complement representation of negative numbers works, the condition in your `while` loop is still true.

Take a look at the following example code for illustration:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  /* defining the variables as unsigned */
  unsigned int first_u = 0;
  unsigned int last_u = -1;

  if (first_u <= last_u)
    printf("less than\n");
  else
    printf("greater or equal\n");

  /* defining the variables as signed */
  int first_s = 0;
  int last_s = -1;

  if (first_s <= last_s)
    printf("less than\n");
  else
    printf("greater or equal\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Other than that, you should use either `<` in your `while`-condition or define the initial value of `last` as `size-1`. Otherwise, if you're searching for an element that is greater than the last element in your array, you will run out of bounds.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly the negative value of middle  is due to overflow (unsigned int).

Also I think you should have : unsigned int last = size-1 because if first becomes equal to last=size the you will use ptrToArray[middle] and middle=size so it will be out of array bounds. This will solve also the case of size =0 mentioned above .

Finally to make your code more easy to read you could write :
`middle =(first+last)/2` which is the middle of [first,last] space, and `equals to first+(last-first)/2` .